# Spring XD Failover

Tags: spring-xd

Does Spring XD support automatic failover when running in distributed mode?  Right now, if I create a simple stream on a setup with two containers, the source gets deployed to one container and the sink get deployed to the other container.  If I shut down the second container, the stream is listed as deployed.  If I undeploy and deploy the stream again, things start working as expected with both source and sink deployed to one container.  I would expect this to happen automatically.  I am using version 1.0.0.M3 with the following example stream:

stream create --definition "time | log" --name ticktock

Answer (score 2):

It it does not support automatic failover.  Better mgmt of streams, e.g. deployment manifests/monitoring, is starting to be developed now, stay tuned.

Cheers,
Mark